# How to hide host groups from Zabbix dashboard?

Tags: filter, monitoring, dashboard, zabbix

As shown in the image below, there's a host group I want to hide (keep out) from Zabbix dashboard.

[image]

I need to remove it, because that host group is like the "master" host group of my system, that is, all other host group is kind of "grouped" in this master host group which I want to keep hidden in my dashboard.

This "master" host group is a summary of the other host groups. For example, if you sum up all the warning counts for Host Groups 1, 2, 3 and 5 (19 + 1 + 22 + 23) you get 65 as the answer, which is the exact "master group" warning count.

So, since this given host group acts as a summary of the other host groups, I don't really need it on the dashboard. Keeping it on the dashboard is even harmful because it doubles the count of everything recorded for the other host groups.

Is there some way to hide that host group from my dashboard view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your widget, you should find an `Exclude host groups` field: set it accordingly.

Note that this will not work with nested groups, as stated [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/monitoring/dashboard/widgets):

> Enter host groups to hide from the widget. This field is auto-complete
>   so starting to type the name of a group will offer a dropdown of
>   matching groups. Specifying a parent host group implicitly selects all
>   nested host groups